# Default Sorting not working for category products in magento

Tags: magento, sorting, categories

I am working on assignment where I need to have unassign the category previous products & need to dynamically assign the bestseller products(top 20)..I am using following code for that:-

```
  $_productCollection = Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'price', 'small_image'))
        ->addAttributeToSort("entity_id","DESC")
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInSiteIds())
        ->setPageSize($productCount);

        // Delete Existing Mapped product from Category

        $delQuery = 'Delete from catalog_category_product where category_id ='.$catId;
        $writeConnection->query($delQuery);

        foreach($_productCollection as $product){

            $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
            if (!in_array($catId, $categoryIds)) {
                $write->query("replace into
`catalog_category_product` (category_id,product_id,position)
VALUES (?,?,0)",array($catId,$product->getEntityId()));
            }
        }

        $process = Mage::getModel('index/indexer')->getProcessByCode('catalog_category_product');
        $process->reindexAll();

        $category->save();
```

Code is working fine but once the dynamic products are assigned to that specific category backend sorting (Default Product List Sort By) for that category products stopped working..I doubt it may be because position is 0 for each replaced product in my query but not yet sure.

If anybody have any suggestions it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The position you have entered in the table is 0 for all products. Magento will then by default sort the products by the order they have been inserted into the category table rather than position.

You need to modify the position accordingly for every product to be able to display them as per default sorting(which is done using position attribute).

Comment: One more thing, get the product positioning and store it into another array. In your while loop, get it from there and insert into position column. If you want to assign top 20 bestsellers into this category then simply increament the sorting by 1 as top selling collection already sorts the products into proper order.

Comment: :-Problem i am facing is that if I set the default sorting of this category from backend either by price or name..it doesn't seems to working..So you means sorting is not working because of position is set to 0 for each product? I am confused that whether sorting by price/name is also dependent on position??

Comment: One more question Do I need to fetch the products current position or I can assign the new positions starting from 1 by incrementing.

Comment: Ohh Now i got your issue, what you can check is go to listing page and change sorting to price, price the raw query in the controller it is hitting. There has to be some column which need to be filled for layering the products on listing page in your case. Also, for top selling products collection, those are sorted by the orders they have got, hence you can directly increment them by 1 in your loop.

Comment: Okay in incremented the same...What about top rated & New In products..In other two categories I need to fetch those & facing same issue there.So will it also be sort by incrementing the position variable starting from 1.....What about the query part..from where I need to check the query ??